# catching sqlite throwables in my code

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to add a record to my sqlite table.

I had a problem saving the record and i saw that in the logcat.

however i would like to prompt the user with a Toast saying there was a problem and what's the error (as written in the logcat)

how can i catch sqlite throwable and show a Toast?

sql catches the error itself and doesn't throw it to its caller?

```
public void addItem(Offer offer) {
    Log.d(MyLogger.TAG, "add saved-offer");
    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_UID, offer.getId().toString());
    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, offer.getAddress());

    // 3. insert
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, // table
            null, // nullColumnHack
            values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column
                        // values

    String text = String.format("item was added to table: {0}", TABLE_NAME);
    Log.d(MyLogger.TAG, text);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    // 4. close
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLiteException not being caught](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283844/sqliteexception-not-being-caught)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related question: [SQLiteException not being caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283844/sqliteexception-not-being-caught)

You need to use the method `db.insertOrThrow()` instead of `insert()`, since insert() won't throw an exception. You can, however, still find out if it failed using insert().

See this documentation: [SQLiteDatabase insert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

> **Returns**
>       the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred

As for getting the exception and printing it, just make the toast in the catch-block with e.GetMessage() as the content