# Android application crashes unexpectedly while executing catch block

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I am new in Android and I'm not getting why it is happening.

In my database I am using `rollno` as primary key.

This code works perfectly and inserts data into database but when i try to insert data with roll number that is already present in the database it should give message that "Data already present",but it crashes unexpectedly.

```
if (v.getId()==R.id.b1) {
    int rollno,marks;
    String name,m1,rno;
    rno=t1.getText().toString();
    name=t2.getText().toString();
    m1=t3.getText().toString();
    rollno=Integer.parseInt(rno);
    marks=Integer.parseInt(m1);

    try {
        db.execSQL("insert into stud values('" + rollno + "','" + name + "','" + marks + "');");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data already present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
D/SensorManager﹕ unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+*cf+(
D/Sensors﹕ Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
I/Sensors﹕ sendDelay --- 200000000
D/SensorManager﹕ JNI - sendDelay
I/SensorManager﹕ Set normal delay = true
D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 4  name= BMA222 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+*fa88
W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
D/SensorManager﹕ unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+*fa88
D/Sensors﹕ Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
I/Sensors﹕ sendDelay --- 200000000
D/SensorManager﹕ JNI - sendDelay
I/SensorManager﹕ Set normal delay = true
D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 4  name= BMA222 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+)(+/(
W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
D/SensorManager﹕ unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+)(+/(
D/Sensors﹕ Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
I/Sensors﹕ sendDelay --- 200000000
D/SensorManager﹕ JNI - sendDelay
I/SensorManager﹕ Set normal delay = true
D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 4  name= BMA222 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+*cf+(
W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 333K, 11% free 9617K/10695K, paused 14ms+4ms, total 72ms
D/SensorManager﹕ unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+*cf+(
D/Sensors﹕ Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
I/Sensors﹕ sendDelay --- 200000000
D/SensorManager﹕ JNI - sendDelay
I/SensorManager﹕ Set normal delay = true
D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 4  name= BMA222 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+*fa88
W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
D/SensorManager﹕ unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+*fa88
D/Sensors﹕ Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
I/Sensors﹕ sendDelay --- 200000000
D/SensorManager﹕ JNI - sendDelay
I/SensorManager﹕ Set normal delay = true
D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 4  name= BMA222 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+)(+/(
W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
D/SensorManager﹕ unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+)(+/(
D/Sensors﹕ Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
I/Sensors﹕ sendDelay --- 200000000
D/SensorManager﹕ JNI - sendDelay
I/SensorManager﹕ Set normal delay = true
W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 4  name= BMA222 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+-+88(
D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419222a0)
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
            at com.example.raju.myapp1.MyActivity.onClick(MyActivity.java:111)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you put your log?

Comment: post your logcat error..may be there is an issue with the toast..

Comment: insted getApplicationContext() use classname.this n try...

Comment: have you open database before execute insert query ?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of [makeText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)) method has to be either `Activity` or `Application`.
Use the reference to your `Activity` object as a first argument to `makeText` method.

Answer (score 0):

**You are expecting that this `Exception` will be caught by the `catch` block but that's what actually not happening**

---

I am guessing that the `rollNo` field in your database is specified as a **primary key** ,and when  you try to reinsert the same roll number again then this SQLITE exception arises. So you need to check before inserting any record in the database that whether that particular roll number is present there or not.

I am going to give you some pseudo code

```
rollnumber=enteredRolNumber

if(enteredRollNumberisInDatabase)
{
   //No insertion and a message that this roll number already exists
}
else
{
   //Do your insertion here
}
```

And in your code,There is no check like this,you are doing it like

```
 try {
            db.execSQL("insert into stud values('" + rollno + "','" + name + "','" + marks + "');");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data already present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

Comment: [see this too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283844/sqliteexception-not-being-caught)